# Язык описания API событийной системы

Tags: websocket, веб-служба

Понемногу планируем рефакторинг сервиса с переходом на событийную модель и вебсокеты. Для описания HTTP использовали Swagger, с ним все понятно, но для новой модели непонятно даже по какому запросу вытаскивать необходимое из гугла. Какие языки описания существуют (существуют ли?) для описания событийного (потокового) API?

Comment: [WSDL](https://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl20/)

Comment: @PavelMayorov оох, я и не знал, что это общая спецификация. Хотелось бы попробовать найти чуть более человекоудобный формат, если такой существует, конечно.

Comment: [AsyncAPI](https://www.asyncapi.com/)? (UPD: посмотрел на дату и офигел.)

Comment: @D-side выглядит как ровно то, что я искал, жир